# Detect the number of unique values in an array

Tags: delphi, data-structures

I am looking for an efficient way to detect the number of unique values in an array.

My current approach:

1. Quicksort array of integers
2. Then run a loop to compare elements.

In code:

```
  yearHolder := '';
  for I := 0 to  High(yearArray) do
  begin
    currYear := yearArray[i];
    if (yearHolder <> currYear) then
    begin
      yearHolder := currYear;
      Inc(uniqueYearNumber);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: What version of Delphi?  2009 has a number of generic data structures that would make this a lot simpler.

Comment: Hi Jim, 
I use D2009 but to be honest  I have a hard time to find any good examples of generics in Delphi; and cannot transpose Java into Delphi the way I would like. Any examples you can share ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example with the THashedStringList:

```
hl := THashedStringList.Create; // in Inifiles
try
  hl.Sorted := True;
  hl.Duplicates := dupIgnore; // ignores attempts to add duplicates
  for i := 0 to  High(yearArray) do
    hl.Add(yearArray[i]);
  uniqueYearCount := hl.Count;
finally
  hl.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example, it helped. 
I did not use before HashStrings.

Comment: Does the dupIgnore statement work without declaring h1 to be sorted? (See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064446/why-doesnt-thashedstringlist-ignore-duplicates )

Comment: My bad, I forgot the dupIgnore doesn't work without Sorted := True;

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can use this algorithm:

1. Create a hash table that maps year to count of occurrences.
2. For each number in your array, put a corresponding entry in a hash table.
3. When done, get the number of entries in the hash.

However, in your case, your variables are named "year". If this is really a year, this is simpler, because years have a very limited range. Say, the range 0-3000 should be enough. So, instead of a hash table, you can use a simple array of counters. Initialize it with 0s. Then when you see the year 2009, increment the element arr[2009]. At the end, count the number of elements with arr[i] >= 1.

Comment: Depends on what is meant by unique. Count == 1 will count only the non-duplicated items. count >= 1 will cound all the items.

Comment: ...but his solution is more consistent with >= 1, so you are right; I'm updating my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the good description. With the example below. It helped. 
Delphi is limited with the data structures.

Answer (score 0):

A minor deviation from the plan could be more worthwhile: never add duplicates to the array in the first place, or add them directly to the proposed hash array.

Up till D2009, there is only **THashedStringList** (which needs a bunch of costly number -> string conversions and hashes on strings to operate), but if you have D2009 then the **Generics.Collections** unit has some interesting data structures.

Comment: No need for number-to-string conversions. Delphi has TBucketList, in the Contnrs unit, with "specializations" for a few data types, including Integer. (It's not called a hash table, but that doesn't mean that's not what it is.)

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi using DeHL we say:
List uniqueWidgets := List.Create( MassiveListOfNonUniqueWidgets.Distinct());

:P

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend adding the items to a *Set* and, once completed, reading the size of the resulting *Set*.  Because *Set*s do not allow duplicates, in Java, DDL, .Net, and many (if not all languages), this is a safe, cheap and reliable method.

Answer (score -2):

A more efficient algorithm would be to dump everything a hash table (not sure if delphi even has this).

1. Iterate through the list (in this case, yearArray) and use the values as keys in the hash table.
2. Retreive the number of keys in the hash table.

Comment: It is...we must have started writing our posts at the same time. The fact that we agree should say something :-)