# Why doesn't THashedStringList ignore duplicates?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I have the following code:

```
var
  sl: THashedStringList;
begin
  sl:= THashedStringList.Create;
  sl.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
  sl.Add('12345');
  sl.Add('12345');
  sl.Add('12345');
  sl.Add('12345');
  sl.Add('12345');
  sl.Add('12345');
  sl.Add('12345');
  ShowMessage(IntToSTr(sl.Count));
end;
```

But when I see `sl.Count`, it gives me 7. What is the bug in this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set the `Sorted` property to TRUE in order to have the list ignore duplicates. The property is inherited from `TStringList`, and if you look at the documentation for `TStringList.Duplicates` you will find:

> **Note:** Duplicates does nothing if the list is not sorted.

Comment: And that's because THashedStringList inherits its Duplicates property from TStringList, as well as its behavior for the Add method. There's nothing special about THashedStringList in this Pavan's example.