# count unique values in array

Tags: arrays, count, unique, pascal

I'm having difficulty counting the number of unique values in an array. I can't really use [i+1] to evaluate, because it may count any values after the i+1th position as unique when there are in fact duplicated later on in the array (see 28 and 29) ...any ideas? Help is greatly appreciated!

[28, 28, 29, 30, 01, 28, 02, 29]

```
function CalcDiscretePeriods(const Arr: Array):Integer;
var
   i: Integer;
begin
   for i:= 0 to High(Arr)-1 do
   begin
       if (Arr[i]<>Arr[i+1]) then countD:= countD + 1;
   end;
end;
```

(I'm using MacOSX,Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.4 [2014/02/26] for i386 if that's relevant).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect the number of unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988730/detect-the-number-of-unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: Generally, it is very easy if the array is sorted. Then you can compare `Arr[i]` with `Arr[i + 1]` and the latter is either equal or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Out of personal experience you can use the the following algorithm to successfully count the unique values from the array.

You will require a second Array say for example 'uniqueArray' (ideally a hashmap like datastructure would be better than an array)

1) Iterate through each element 'i' from your existing array 'Arr' from i=0 to High(Arr)-1

2) For each 'i', copy this value into the second array 'uniqueArray' **ONLY if** uniqueArr does not already have this value(requires for loop of each element in uniqueArr).

3) On successful copy,  increment count.

I am afraid I am not familiar with the language to provide any practical examples.

Answer (score 0):

A particularly slow, yet memory efficient method would be to iterate through the array twice. The following is an Extended Pascal (ISO standard 10206) compliant excerpt:

```
type
    integerNonNegative = 0..maxInt;

{ returns the number of unique values in `list` }
function discretePeriods(
        protected list: array[lowerBound..upperBound: integer] of integer
    ): integerNonNegative;
    { determines whether `reference` occurs only once in `list` }
    function isUnique(protected reference: type of list[lowerBound]): Boolean;
        { counts the number of occurences of a `reference` value }
        function occurences: integerNonNegative;
        var
            i: type of lowerBound;
            n: integerNonNegative value 0;
        begin
            for i := lowerBound to upperBound do
            begin
                if list[i] = reference then
                begin
                    n := n + 1;
                end;
            end;
            occurences := n;
        end;
    begin
        isUnique := occurences = 1;
    end;
var
    i: type of lowerBound;
    uniqueValues: integerNonNegative value 0;
begin
    for i := lowerBound to upperBound do
    begin
        if isUnique(list[i]) then
        begin
            uniqueValues := uniqueValues + 1;
        end;
    end;
    discretePeriods := uniqueValues;
end;
```

Another faster, but memory-intensive method is, as it’s already been suggested, to *divide* the *analyze step* from the *calculation step*. In Extended Pascal this can look like the following:

```
const
    integersMaximum = 4194303;

type
    integerNonNegative = 0..maxInt;
    integersRange = -integersMaximum..+integersMaximum;
    {$setLimit=8388608}{ only in GPC }
    integers = set of integersRange value [];

{ returns the number of unique values in `list` }
function discretePeriods(
        protected list: array[lowerBound..upperBound: integer] of integersRange
    ): integerNonNegative;
var
    population: integers;

    procedure populate;
    var
        i: type of lowerBound;
    begin
        { transform ordered list to “unordered” `set` }
        for i := lowerBound to upperBound do
        begin
            population := population + [list[i]];
        end;
    end;

    function duplicates: integers;
    var
        i: type of lowerBound;
        m: integers;
    begin
        for i := lowerBound to upperBound do
        begin
            { construct a set of all values that appear more than once }
            if not (list[i] in population) then
            begin
                m := m + [list[i]];
            end;
            { at any rate remove the current item from `population` }
            population := population - [list[i]];
        end;
        duplicates := m;
    end;
var
    n: integerNonNegative;
begin
    populate;
    { calculation step }
    n := card(population);
    discretePeriods := n - card(duplicates);
end;
```

Finally, it depends on your specific use scenario. Possibly you’ll (eventually) need the array to be sorted anyway, so the method [Rudy Velthuis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377335/count-unique-values-in-array#comment68060202_40377335) suggested might be the most suitable for you.